# 07 Acura TL types S

Tags: noise, automatic-transmission, acura, tl

Car has a loud whining sounds throughout all gears including neutral. The sound doesn't change as the wheel turns, but it does increases as engine is revved. It's not a squealing sound.

I have changed the power steering pump, high pressure line and serpentine belt, and the sound is still there.

How can I tell if it’s the torque converter?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm not sure why you'd think changing the power steering belt would make a difference? If there's a problem with the power steering pump, you need to check the pump itself. Does the noise change pitch at all when you turn the steering wheel? What type of whine is it? Is it a sharp noise (like a squeal) or a lower pitched whine? Any other information you can provide?

Comment: Does the whine increase in pitch and/or volume when the engine is revved or when the car is moving faster?

Comment: Sry Not belt, the pump. No squealing, does not change sound as wheel turns. Increases as engine is revved. Parts changed include  power steering pump, high pressure line n serpentine belt.

Comment: Have you checked the bearings in the pulleys and rollers which route and tension the serpentine belt? A bad bearing could create this sound; take a look at [this question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/302/how-to-pinpoint-a-noisy-bearing-or-pulley?rq=1). And why do you suspect the torque converter? Does the transmission otherwise shift and operate correctly? How many miles on the vehicle?